# Want to put a method into a QThread

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

How to add a method within the class to a thread to execute?

I do not want to put "Pup" into a seperate class that inherits QThread as this is just an abstraction of some Legacy code I am working on.

```
void Dog::Pup()
{
     printf("pup");
}

void Dog::Init()
{
     QThread *dogThread = new QThread();
     Pup->moveToThread(dogThread); //this is all wrong
     Pup->connect(dogThread, ?, Pup, SLOT(Pup), ?)
     dogThread.start();
}
```

Comment: [Everyone is just crazy about this little article](http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/).  Hope it helps!

Comment: That article is taking a class, not a methode, and adding it to qthread.  I have read this before, this approach is not to feasable with the code I am working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
void Dog::Init()
{
     QThread *dogThread = new QThread;
     connect(dogThread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(Pup()), Qt::DirectConnection);
     dogThread->start();
}
```

It basically creates a new `QThread` named `dogThread` and connects it's `started()` signal to the method you want to run inside the thread (`Dog::Pup()` which must be a slot).

When you use a `Qt::QueuedConnection` the slot would be executed in the receiver's thread, but when you use `Qt::DirectConnection` the slot will be invoked immediately, and because `started()` is emitted from the `dogThread`, the slot will also be called from the `dogThread`. You find more information about the connection types here: [Qt::ConnectionType](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum).

Answer (score 0):

Read the Detailed description in the page http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run a single function in another thread, you should check out the methods in the `QtConcurrent` namespace.