# moveToThread() and than start() works with not constructed object?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have something like this:

> main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    static Communication *c = new Communication();
    return a.exec();
}
```

> communication.cpp

**t is Qthread object...**

```
Communication::Communication() 
{
    client = new EchoClient(QUrl(QStringLiteral("ws://localhost:1234")), 0);
    client->moveToThread(&t);
    connect(&t, SIGNAL(started()), client, SLOT(proces()));
    t.start(QThread::HighestPriority);
}
```

How is it possible that when I call constructor, that object is not created yet but will be in next iteration of main loop? I am trying to achieve that firstly, object will be created and than moved to thread and will be paralely listenning to messages while waiting for user input.

Thx

**EDIT**

I just want to add client to another thread because in main thread I want to wait for user input like this if I enhance this a little bit

```
Communication::Communication() 
{
    client = new EchoClient(QUrl(QStringLiteral("ws://localhost:1234")), 0);
    client->moveToThread(&t);
    connect(&t, SIGNAL(started()), client, SLOT(proces()));
    t.start(QThread::HighestPriority);


std::cout << "\n***************CLIENT MENU***************\n";
std::cout << "(1): SHOW
std::cout << "(2): EXIT\n";
std::cout << "***************************************************\n";

std::cin >> m_choice;

}
```

Problem is it will show menu and it will be blocked and not recieve any message

Comment: Little confused on what you're saying; next iteration of main loop - doesn't look like you're calling it recursively (which would be UB)

Comment: @UKMonkey main works as a event loop right? so I noticed it will be created after it reaches a.exec() again

Comment: " main works as a event loop right" no, it's not a loop at all, that's what a.exec is

Comment: How do you know the object is not created? It looks like it is created. the thread is just not started yet.

Comment: @UKMonkey if you got what I meant feel free to edit my question

Comment: @aladin8848 no idea yet :)

Comment: "How is it possible that when I call constructor, that object is not created yet but will be in next iteration of main loop?" Please clarify *explicitly* which constructor, which object and which loop you mean. A loop is almost always defined with `for`, `while` or `do`.

Comment: if `t` is no pointer it will already be constructed. directly before the custom code if the constructor. `t.start()` does not construct the thread but start it. Member initialization takes place before constructor code.

Comment: @MartinNyolt in this case the loop is the Qt event loop started by `a.exec();`

Comment: @MartinNyolt  I meant object Client is not constructed. I assume because incomingmessage slot is not reached

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Console I/O is blocking: when `cin >> m_choice` is waiting for user input in the main thread, the main thread can't do anything else. The event loop won't run, no slots in the main thread will run, etc.

You may wish to move the console I/O based menu system to a dedicated thread, and interface it with the rest of the system via signals/slots.

Comment: This sounds good, thx but I wonder, how can I move just a method to a threaad? is it possible? lets say method showMenu() I never found this, just objects. So maybe it is good to create menu object?

Comment: I have found this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241422/want-to-put-a-method-into-a-qthread

Comment: Methods that are interacting with gui objects can only execute in the main thread. Any other method can be executed in a worker thread using `QtConcurrent::run`. It is then idiomatic to emit a signal to get data out of such a method, or use `QFutureWatcher` to get such a signal.